Substack Publication Custom Domain and Cloudflare: Error 1014
I just set my domain evancarroll.com (which I've had for decades) with Substack using my new Substack Publication. I did this using a CNAME at substack.evancarroll.com. However when I browse to it, I see

Error 1014 Ray ID: 8f9e516d9e474fba • 2024-12-30 01:39:47 UTC
CNAME Cross-User Banned

This is what the screen of the error looks like,

